# Looping through a list in Python and creating new objects based on items

Tags: python, list, for-loop, naming

Let's say I have a list of objects (in this instance, dataframes)

```
myList = [dataframe1, dataframe2, dataframe3 ...]
```

I want to loop over my list and create new objects based on the names of the list items. What I want is a pivoted version of each dataframe, called "dataframe[X]_pivot" where [X] is the identifier for that dataframe.

My pseudocode looks something like:

```
for d in myList:
    d+'_pivot' = d.pivot_table(index='columnA', values=['columnB'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

And my desired output looks like this:

```
myList = [dataframe1, dataframe2 ...]
dataframe1_pivoted # contains a pivoted version of dataframe1
dataframe2_pivoted # contains a pivoted version of dataframe2
dataframe3_pivoted # contains a pivoted version of dataframe3
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

John

Comment: Usually if you want more than one of the same kind of data you put it in a list.

Comment: why not `pivots = [d.pivot_table(index='columnA', values=['columnB'], aggfunc=np.sum) for d in myList]`?

Comment: @PeterWood - I'm confused by your comment; there is already a list involved

Comment: @ŁukaszR. Not quite what I had in mind.

I want to have created a set of pivoted dataframes, one for each original dataframe.

e.g.

dataframe1_pivoted, dataframe2_pivoted

Lukasz, your solution results in a single df called '
pivots'

Comment: Sure, but why do you want to do that? I smell an XY Problem here.

Comment: What's an XY problem?  

What I want to do take my various dataframes, let's say data from multiple reporting systems, and aggregate them all up in the same way. To give more background - the for loop is also doing various other operations, not just a pivot.

Comment: Rather than having separate dataframes, have a list `dataframes`, and a list `dataframe_pivots`.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* want to do that. Creating a variables dynamically is almost always a very bad idea. The correct thing to do would be to simply use an appropriate data structure to hold your data, e.g. either a list (as your elements are all just numbered, you can just as well access them via an index) or a dictionary (if you really really want to give a name to each individual thing):

```
pivoted_list = []
for df in mylist:
    pivoted_df = #whatever you need to to to turn a dataframe into a pivoted one
    pivoted_list.append(pivoted_df)

#now access your results by index
do_something(pivoted_list[0])
do_something(pivoted_list[1])
```

The same thing can be expressed as a list comprehension. Assume `pivot` is a function that takes a dataframe and turns it into a pivoted frame, then this is equivalent to the loop above:

```
pivoted_list = [pivot(df) for df in mylist]
```

If you are certain that you want to have *names* for the elements, you can create a dictionary, by using `enumerate` like this:

```
pivoted_dict = {}
for index, df in enumerate(mylist):
    pivoted_df = #whatever you need to to to turn a dataframe into a pivoted one
    dfname = "dataframe{}_pivoted".format(index + 1)
    pivoted_dict[dfname] = pivoted_df

#access results by name
do_something(pivoted_dict["dataframe1_pivoted"])
do_something(pivoted_dict["dataframe2_pivoted"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve that is:

```
globals()[d+'_pivot'] = d.pivot_table(...)
```

[edit] after looking at your edit, I see that you may want to do something like this:

```
for i, d in enumerate(myList):
    globals()['dataframe%d_pivoted' % i] = d.pivot_table(...)
```

However, as others have suggested, it is unadvisable to do so if that is going to create lots of global variables.

**There are better ways (read: data structures) to do so.**

Comment: Hi @mescalinum, doesn't work for me. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'

Comment: Downvoted - suggesting the creation of global variables over simply using an appropriate data structure is IMO a very bad idea.

Comment: @l4mpi: it's the OP asking to do so. what I can do is to discourage that practice, but since IT IS possible, here it is. I do not endorse your downvote.

Comment: @mescalinum if OP was having a headache and would be asking about the best way to amputate their head, would you tell them how to do that, or would you rather tell them why they should not do so and recommend alternative ways of dealing with it? It's a classic XY problem, OP is asking about it simply because they don't know better.

Comment: @l4mpi: I assumed OP **knows** the better ways (i.e. lists) to do it, but wants this hack on purpose. Indeed, he uses a list as input and iterates over that, so he must know at least that python has lists :-)

Comment: @l4mpi: thank you for the help. Also, +1 your incisiveness - I am indeed ignorant, rather than attempting to do something inadvisable. In fact, I don't really understand yet WHY creating variables dynamically is a bad idea, but I'll figure it out.

Comment: @mescalinum also thanks, for assuming I'm more competent than my use of lists suggests :)